# Share content using Intent to Facebook Lite Android

Tags: android, facebook

Am using the following code for sharing the content directly to facebook app,

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent
                .putExtra(
                        android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "Some text");
        PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                shareIntent, 0);
        for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
            if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                        activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
                break;
            }
        }
```

it is working perfectly for facebook app, but facing issues with facebook lite app. For user who installed facebook-lite not able to share the content, It simply display the splash screen of fb-lite app. Please help me out.

Comment: use new facebooksdk4.5.1 ,https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk refer this link also@ Sankari S

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i dont want to integrate sdk. Is there any option to share using intent

Comment: don't know if facebook lite can achieve that... the best way is by using facebook sdk.

Comment: @SankariS for this you can use set package name in the intent, like this intent.setPackage("YOUR PACKAGE NAME HERE"); . kindly check my answer

Answer (score 3):

You acheive this by setting the package name in the intent.

It will look for the specified app, If present it will open the app. other wise it will show the error message that **there is no app can perform this action**.
Try the approach for sharing using the Android default intent.

**// Using Facebook App**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Example text"); 
intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");      
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

**// Using Facebook Lite App**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Example text"); 
intent.setPackage("com.facebook.lite");      
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Let me know how it goes...

**NOTE : Facebook share will work fine at its best when using the Facebook SDK (use version greater than 4.X - recommended )**

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(R.string.share_subject));
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Example text");    

activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, activity.getString(R.string.share_title)));
```

Comment: i need to directly share with facebook instead of listing all apps

Comment: @SankariS for this you can use set package name in the intent, like this intent.setPackage("YOUR PACKAGE NAME HERE"); . kindly check my answer

Comment: in my knowledge if you need directly share facebook app you have to integrate facebooksdk greater than 4 @SankariS